# for(auto e : elements) may cause one of elements to be wanted to be removed from vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have some classes:

```
struct Listenable{
    virtual void removeListener(Listener * listener) = 0;
};

class Listener{
public: //that way example is simpler
    unsigned myCode = 0;
    Listenable * subject = 0;

    Listener(unsigned myCode, Listenable * subject) 
        : myCode(myCode), subject(subject){}

    void notify(unsigned value){
        if(value == myCode){
            a->removeListener(this);
        }
    }
};

class A : public Listenable{
public: //that way example is simpler
    std::vector<Listener*> listeners;

   void fun(unsigned value){
        for(auto listener : listeners){
            b->notify(value);
        }
    }

    void removeListener(Listener * listener){
        auto it = std::find(listeners.begin(), listeners.end(), listener);
        if(it != listeners.end()){
            listeners.erase(it);
        }
    }
};
```

and the code:

```
A a;

Listener * l1 = new Listener(5, a);
Listener * l2 = new Listener(7, a);

a.listeners.push_back(l1);
a.listeners.push_back(l2);
a.notify(3); //OK
a.notify(5); //error
```

I get the `vector iterator not incrementable` error in `a.notify(5)`.

I know that it's because when I notify the `l1` listener (inside of `for` loop of `A::fun(5)`), it decides to unsubscribe (call to `A::removeListener`).

**But how to solve this?** I want to iterate throw all the listeners and notify them about an event. **I cannot assume** if any of them (or how many of them) will want to remove itself from the list (it can happens as a reaction to event **or somewhere else**). I also cannot assume **which** circumstances will force specific Listener to call `A::removeListener(this)` and **when**.

I could change `void notify(...)` to `bool notify(...)` where `return true` would mean "please, remove me". **But I cannot be sure** that user won't call `A::removeListener(this)` inside of his custom `notify(...){...}` (from the class that inherit from `Listener`) anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to mark the element to suppress, and remove it after the loop, something like:

```
class A : public Listenable{
public: //that way example is simpler
    std::vector<Listener*> listeners;

   void fun(unsigned value){
        for (auto listener : listeners){
            if (listener) { // not marked as deleted
                listener->notify(value);
            }
        }
        // remove 'mark_as_deleted' listeners
        listeners.erase(std::remove(listeners.begin(), listeners.end(), nullptr),
            listeners.end();
    }

    void removeListener(Listener* listener){
        auto it = std::find(listeners.begin(), listeners.end(), listener);
        if (it != listeners.end()){
            *it = nullptr; // mark as deleted.
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There's only one way to go if the vector might be changed while you iterate over it:

*Iterate over a copy!*

Unless, of course, you can just change the data-structure.

Comment: It's very expensive to copy the vector before each iteration loop, but if I would not be able to change the data-structure, that's an option. Up-voted to neutralize the down-vote.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. It's a sane suggestion, and what I was going to suggest myself.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a probable use case for `std::list`, where iterators don't become invalidated when the list is changed (unless the thing they refer to is removed).

If you had a `std::list<Listener*>`, you could step through the list with two iterators  `current` and `next` (for example), keep `next` one ahead of `current`, notify `*current` in every iteration and be sure that `next` will still be a valid iterator afterwards. Then set `current = next; ++next;`, and the issue is neatly sidestepped.

Comment: In general, a `std::list` has far worse performance-characteristics. Also, that change might not be possible. Still, it works, so +1

Comment: That, alas, is true, although I suspect that the choice of container for the listener pointers is not a hotspot for performance optimization. Unless random access is required (did not seem to be the case) or most listeners have trivial actions associated with them. If random access is required, the `stable_vector` UnknownGosu mentioned looks interesting, but otherwise (without having benchmarked it) it should share the same non-locality problems that make `std::list` so slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't control whether your listeners may try to remove themselves from thew collection, you should consider using a container with stable iterators. One good example would be stable_vector class from Boost (see the documentation here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.stable_vector).
Its memory footprint is of course bigger than one of std::vector, but overall algorithmic complexity is same. A good feature you get is particular element iterator stays valid as long as element is present in the container. You can rewrite your iteration like this to make it tolerate removals:

```
for (auto iter = listeners.begin(); iter != listeners.end(); ) // note we don't auto increment here
    auto next_iter = iter + 1; // remember the next element
    iter->do_something(); // may remove itself from the container
    iter = next_iter;
}
```

EDIT: Or, as [wintermute](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4301306/wintermute) suggested, you may use `std::list` as the stable container, although it has pretty worse performance when it comes to iteration, and its memory usage is way less efficient than one of any vector.

Answer (score 1):

Add a boolean flag `isNotifying` to the class `A`.

Set this flag to `true` at the beginning of `fun` and to `false` at the end of `fun`.

Inside `removeListener`, check the flag. If it is `false`, simply remove the listener as you are doing now. Otherwise, add the listener to a second vector of listeners to be removed in the future.

At the very end of `fun`, remove all listeners from said vector of listeners. Then clear said vector.

If `fun` needs to be re-entrant, use an `int` instead of a boolean flag and count up/down.

Comment: I was lately thinking about setting pointer to 0 instead of deleting it in `removeListener`, and remove at the very end of `fun` (check for `0` inside `for` would be needed). That's quite nice variation :)